# JConsole with private RMI hostname

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jconsole

I have a JBoss application sever running with **-Djava.rmi.server.hostname** parameter set to **private IP**, which prevent's me to connect with JConsole.

My other options are:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=31337 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I can't change the **-Djava.rmi.server.hostname** parameter to public IP, because application components are communicating using private IP.

Is there a workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are the application components using the private IP? If you can't change that, you'll have to organize a tunnel.

Comment: It was designed like that, and I cannot change it. Do you have any examples for the tunnel configuration?

Comment: The requirement to use the private IP conflicts with the requirement to connect to it from outside with JConsole. Something has to change.